# How to code for new variable based on where majority of time is?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a DateTime data frame for sleep data. I'd like to change the "mixed" variable to "day" sleep or "night" sleep based on where the majority of sleep took place with 8 am and 8 pm when the sleep crosses the cut-off.

```
    #Current database
    id<-c("m1","m1","m1","m2","m2","m2","m3","m4","m4")
    x<-c("2020-01-03 10:00:00","2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 19:20:00","2020-01-05 10:00:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 20:50:00","2020-01-06 06:30:00","2020-01-08 06:30:00","2020-01-08 07:50:00")
    start<-strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    y<-c("2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 19:20:00","2020-01-03 20:50:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 20:50:00","2020-01-05 22:00:00","2020-01-06 07:40:00","2020-01-08 07:50:00","2020-01-08 08:55:00")
    end<-strptime(y,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    mydata<-data.frame(id,start,end)

    #Current ouput
    df1<-mydata %>%
    mutate_at(vars(start, end), ymd_hms) %>%
    mutate(start_hour = hour(start), 
     end_hour = hour(end), 
     day.night = case_when(start_hour >= 8 & end_hour >= 8 & end_hour < 20 ~ "day", 
                           start_hour >= 20 &  (end_hour < 8 | end_hour <= 23) |
                             (start_hour < 8 & end_hour < 8)~ "night",
                           TRUE ~ "mixed"))



    id               start                 end start_hour end_hour day.night
    1 m1 2020-01-03 10:00:00 2020-01-03 16:00:00         10       16       day
    2 m1 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 19:20:00         16       19       day
    3 m1 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2020-01-04 20:50:00         19       20     mixed
    4 m2 2020-01-05 10:00:00 2020-01-05 15:20:00         10       15       day
    5 m2 2020-01-05 15:20:00 2020-01-05 20:50:00         15       20     mixed
    6 m2 2020-01-05 20:50:00 2020-01-05 22:00:00         20       22     night
    7 m3 2020-01-06 06:30:00 2020-01-06 07:40:00          6        7     night
    8 m4 2020-01-08 06:30:00 2020-01-08 07:50:00          6        7     night
    9 m4 2020-01-08 07:50:00 2020-01-08 08:55:00          7        8     mixed
```

Currently, when sleep intercepts the cutoffs the new variable output is set to "mixed".

Edit: I would like where data is mixed for sleep to be categorised based on where most time is spent, i.e. in row 3: 40 minutes was day and 50 minutes was night, so this would now = night, and in row 5: 4hrs 40 minutes was day and 50 minutes was night, so this would now = day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to use a different approach or if it can be done with this function?

Comment: What is your expected output? In your example for the first 'mixed' occurrence, do you want this to change to 'night', since the case spent 40 minutes sleeping before 8pm and 50 minutes sleeping after 8pm?

Comment: Yes, I'll go clarify that better in my question @kstew thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lubridate` and `dplyr`, you can categorize day and night using `if_else`. I've also adjusted the data as per the comment.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#data
id <- c("m1", "m1", "m1", "m2", "m2", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m4")
x <- c("2020-01-03 10:00:00", "2020-01-03 16:00:00", "2020-01-03 19:20:00", "2020-01-05 10:00:00", "2020-01-05 15:20:00", "2020-01-05 20:50:00", "2020-01-06 06:30:00", "2020-01-08 06:30:00", "2020-01-08 07:50:00")
start <- strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
y <- c("2020-01-03 16:00:00", "2020-01-03 19:20:00", "2020-01-03 00:50:00", "2020-01-05 15:20:00", "2020-01-05 20:50:00", "2020-01-05 22:00:00", "2020-01-06 07:40:00", "2020-01-08 07:50:00", "2020-01-08 08:55:00")
end <- strptime(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mydata <- data.frame(id, start, end)

#start and end times
daystart <- as.POSIXct('08:00:00', format = "%T")
nightstart <- as.POSIXct('20:00:00', format = "%T")
dayend <- as.POSIXct('19:59:00', format = "%T")
nightend <- as.POSIXct('07:59:00', format = "%T")

df1 <- mydata %>% mutate(start1 = as.POSIXct(sub("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+", Sys.Date(), start)),
                                        end1 = as.POSIXct(sub("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+", Sys.Date(), end)),
                                        day = ifelse(start1 > daystart & start1 < dayend & end1 < dayend & end1 > daystart, as.interval(start1, end1),
                                                      ifelse(start1 > daystart & start1 < dayend & end1 < dayend & end1 < daystart, as.interval(start1, dayend),
                                                      ifelse(start1 > daystart & start1 < dayend & end1 > dayend, as.interval(start1, dayend),
                                                      ifelse(end1 > daystart & end1 < dayend, as.interval(daystart, end1), 0)))),
                                        night = ifelse(end1 > nightstart, as.interval(nightstart, end1),
                                                      ifelse(start1 < nightend & end1 > nightend, as.interval(start1, nightend),
                                                      ifelse(start1 < nightend & end1 < nightend, as.interval(start1, end1),                                                      
                                                      ifelse(start1 > nightstart & end1 < nightend, as.interval(start1, end1),
                                                      ifelse(start1 < nightstart & end1 < daystart, as.interval(nightstart, end1), 0))))),
                                        day.night = ifelse(abs(day) > abs(night), "day", "night"))

df1 %>% select(names(mydata), day.night)

#  id               start                 end day.night
#1 m1 2020-01-03 10:00:00 2020-01-03 16:00:00       day
#2 m1 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 19:20:00       day
#3 m1 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2020-01-03 00:50:00     night
#4 m2 2020-01-05 10:00:00 2020-01-05 15:20:00       day
#5 m2 2020-01-05 15:20:00 2020-01-05 20:50:00       day
#6 m2 2020-01-05 20:50:00 2020-01-05 22:00:00     night
#7 m3 2020-01-06 06:30:00 2020-01-06 07:40:00     night
#8 m4 2020-01-08 06:30:00 2020-01-08 07:50:00     night
#9 m4 2020-01-08 07:50:00 2020-01-08 08:55:00       day
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt but unfortunately, this doesn't work if row #3 was changed to 2020-01-04 00:50:00 as it outputs "day" instead of "night". I've realised this was a problem in my original question output and have edited this.

Comment: @Sparky, I've updated my answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `Overlap` function from the `DescTools` package.

```r
library(plyr); library(tidyverse); library(DescTools)

mydata %>% mutate(r=rownames(.)) %>% ddply(.,.(r), function(x)
  x %>% mutate(overlap = Overlap(c(as.POSIXct(sub("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+", Sys.Date(), start)),
                           as.POSIXct(sub("\\d+-\\d+-\\d+", Sys.Date(), end))),
                         c(as.POSIXct('08:00:00',format='%T'),as.POSIXct('20:00:00',format='%T'))),
               sleep.length = difftime(end,start,units='s') %>% as.numeric(),
               day.night = ifelse(overlap > (sleep.length/2), 'day','night')))

  id               start                 end r overlap sleep.length day.night
1 m1 2020-01-03 10:00:00 2020-01-03 16:00:00 1   21600        21600       day
2 m1 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2   12000        12000       day
3 m1 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2020-01-03 20:50:00 3    2400         5400     night
4 m2 2020-01-05 10:00:00 2020-01-05 15:20:00 4   19200        19200       day
5 m2 2020-01-05 15:20:00 2020-01-05 20:50:00 5   16800        19800       day
6 m2 2020-01-05 20:50:00 2020-01-05 22:00:00 6       0         4200     night
7 m3 2020-01-06 06:30:00 2020-01-06 07:40:00 7       0         4200     night
8 m4 2020-01-08 06:30:00 2020-01-08 07:50:00 8       0         4800     night
9 m4 2020-01-08 07:50:00 2020-01-08 08:55:00 9    3300         3900       day
```

I couldn't get the `Overlap` function to work without splitting the data frame and applying it to each row individually. Using your data, `Overlap` will return the overlapping interval in seconds (43200 seconds to 12 hours).